# C#. Logical riddle with bit operations. Only one bit is set?

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation

This should be easy for C++ people though. But I was asked how to do it in C#. Shouldnt be much of difference.

*How to find out if a long variable has **only one** bit set?*

I cant think anything except some brutal force shifting all bits and counting whats set.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> A non-negative binary integer value x is a power of 2 if `(x&(x-1))` is 0 using 2's complement arithmetic.

Powers of 2 would mean a single bit is set.

http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Is%20Power%20of%202

EDIT:

To allow for the zero case:

```
bool singleBit = x>0 && (x&(x-1))==0
```

Comment: :O  this would've saved me tens of lines of coding a while ago! Can't believe I couldn't think of it, +1!! :)

Comment: This doesn't work for x = 0, you will have to check for that, too.

Comment: @spender: I just bookmarked it before refreshing this page and seeing your comment!! :)

Comment: +1: Just a side note: for negative values the only one having just 1 bit set is `long.MinValue`

Comment: This is a great trick, but the quoted text is not entirely correct. If should say "positive" instead of "non-negative" and it should say "iff" (i.e. "if and only if") instead of "if". The implementation is correct, though.

Answer (score 3):

In C++:

```
unsigned long v;
bool f; // result
f = v && !(v & (v - 1));
```

Explanation: v & (v - 1) == 0 if only one bit is set or v == 0.

Answer (score -1):

Just tried it in PHP:

```
$singleBit = $bits && !($bits & ($bits - 1));
```