# Check if byte has more than one bit set

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte

I'm receiving a 3-byte message back from a serial device when I send it a query in my C# application. The entire message should have at most one bit set, e.g. `$04 00 00` is fine, but not `$04 01 00` or `$05 00 00`.

Bit-shifting and checking each bit is one solution but perhaps there is something more elegant? We can check each byte to see if it's a power of two but I can't come up with a way which looks nicer (not sure about efficiency in these cases either).

As an extension to the problem, I need to match each possible value to an output message, e.g.:
`$01 00 00: Button A pressed`
`$00 02 00: Lever B pulled`
`$00 00 04: Switch C activated`

A case statement is a simple solution, but once again, wondering if there's a pretty way of doing this as well.

Comment: Create a 256-byte table with index 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128 set to 1/true and the rest 0/false. That should at least give you a quick way to check a single byte.

Comment: A switch statement is the best way as it is fast and does not make the code hard to read.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624248/c-logical-riddle-with-bit-operations-only-one-bit-is-set

Comment: How are you doing the output messages? If you are using a switch statement then why not just put all the valid outputs returning what they need to and then have a default that assumes that either more than one bit is set or that an invalid bit is set (if that is possible).

Comment: @Chris I'm currently not outputting the messages. Your idea is good but I would also like to have the ability to check the byte as a function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is one clever trick to check if byte has more one bit set.
`n & (n - 1) != 0`

Comment: See https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2

Comment: Mind the operator precedence though

Comment: Using this in SQL, exactly what I needed, thanks!