# Check if only a specific column was updated in a sql server trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to write a trigger that will execute some logic unless only one specific column was updated, e.g. if only the 'UpdateDate' column was updated then don't bother firing the trigger.

I know I can use [UPDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) and [COLUMNS_UPDATED()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) but it seems difficult to write it in a maintainable way to check if it's just that one column updated. E.g. I could call UPDATE() against each of the other columns in the table but then if someone adds another column and doesn't modify the trigger it will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with this logic:

If

- the column of interest was updated, and
- COLUMNS_UPDATED() has only one bit set

then don't fire the rest of the trigger.

e.g.

```
-- If columns_updated() is bigger than a bigint will take then 
-- just continue. We could deal with this better but not an issue for me.
if datalength(columns_updated())<63 begin 

    declare @colsUpdated bigint
    set @colsUpdated = cast( columns_updated() as bigint ) 

    -- if UpdateDate column was updated AND there was only a single column updated 
    -- don't run the rest of the trigger. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4624295/8479
    -- for discussion of how to check if only one bit of a number is set. If only 
    -- one bit is set then only one col was updated, and we use update() to check 
    -- if it was UpdateDate.
    if update(UpdateDate) 
        and ( @colsUpdated & ( @colsUpdated-1 ) = 0 )
    begin 

        return;
    end 
end
```

Comment: Note this approach can cause the trigger to fire when columns were updated, but the values were not actually changed. See my answer for an alternate approach.

Comment: I agree. In my case I don't care if the column was updated with the same value, but definitely worth keeping in mind as often people will care about that.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005+ I would do it this way:

Assuming `Column4` is the specific column you want to ignore, I would do something like this:

```
select *
into #changedRows
from (
   select Column1, Column2, Column3 from deleted 
   except 
   select Column1, Column2, Column3 from inserted
) x

if not exists (select * from #changedRows)
   return;
```

The advantage of this method is that it will correctly determine not just whether a column was updated, but whether the data was actually **changed**, which is usually all you care about.

Comment: This works quite well but you could skip the temp table and squeeze out a little bit of performance. No point writing all the rows to a temp table when all you care about is if they exist or not. Just move the EXCEPT query as the condition for EXISTS.

Comment: @SeanLange Sure - I copied this code from a trigger where I do something with the changed rows later, but your point is valid.

Comment: I can see this would be useful if that's what you're after, but this suffers from the same problem if you use `UPDATE()` against all the other columns in the table: if someone adds another column and doesn't modify the trigger it will break.