# Golang | How would I check if multiple boolean values are true in a single if statement?

Tags: go, variables

I'm making a program in Golang using the flag package, and I'm trying to check if more than one flag in a specific list is true. Right now, this is my solution:

```
List := 0

if *md5flag {
    List++
}
if *sha1flag {
    List++
}
if *sha256flag {
    List++
}
if *sha512flag {
    List++
}

if List > 1 {
    // Do stuff
    os.Exit(1)  
}
```

Would there be an easier way to do this, and by using a single if statement?

Comment: does go have multiple in sum/map functions? Something like `[md5flag, sha1flag, sha256flag, sha512flag].sum { |f| f ? : 1: 0 }` would be perfect

Comment: Do you really care how many flags are on? Or just if *any* of them are on?  `if *md5flag || *sha1flag || *sha256flag  { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is to check that at most one flag is set and exit immediately in that case, you can use a loop with short circuiting, though I'm not sure if it's more readable for just 4 values:

```
flags := []*bool{md5flag, sha1flag, sha256flag, sha512flag}
seenSetFlag := false
for _, f := range flags {
    if *f {
        if seenSetFlag {
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        seenSetFlag = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go doesn't have any conversion from `bool` to `int`, so you need to use an if-statement in some way.

I would do something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func boolsToInt(flags... bool) int {
    value := 0
    for _, flag := range flags {
        if flag {
            value++
        }
    }
    return value
}

func main() {
    b1, b2, b3, b4 := false, true, true, false
    fmt.Println(boolsToInt(b1, b2, b3, b4))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bitmask. But the bitmask approach is more effective if you set up your flags to be a bitmask to begin with, i.e. the flags should be integers that can be OR'ed together. `bool` in Go doesn't support `|` operator.

With a bitmask, to check if more than one bit is set you can use the trick `x & (x - 1) != 0`. This checks if `x` is a power of two, when it is not, more than one bit is set. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624248/c-logical-riddle-with-bit-operations-only-one-bit-is-set))

```
type alg int

const (
    md5flag alg = 1 << iota
    sha1flag 
    sha256flag
    sha512flag
)

func main() {
    // clients can initialize the value with bitwise-OR
    supportedAlgos := md5flag | sha256flag

    // check if more than one is set
    if supportedAlgos & (supportedAlgos - 1) != 0 {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you can't refactor your code to use a bitmask you may still construct it from the individual bool pointers. But then the approach isn't much different than the one you have right now.

```
func toBitmask(bs ...*bool) int {
    bitmask := 0
    for i, b := range bs {
        if b != nil && *b {
            bitmask |= 1 << i
        }
    }
    return bitmask
}

func main() {
    list := toBitmask(md5flag, sha1flag, sha256flag, sha512flag)

    if list & (list - 1) != 0 {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/PXK_1sS5ZxI